# PhD thesis layouts from around the world

Tags: phd, publications, thesis

About to do this PhD thesis here - but am not really satisfied with my layout. Could somebody point me to some interesting layouts, templates or whatever?

Comment: Check the regulations before going too wild/creative. Some universities are strict about the formatting.

Comment: Absolutely follow David Clarke's advice. I had to write my thesis inside a template file that I was given by my institution.

Comment: Try the Latex template we've applied in our Research Group. As it is a sourceforge project, you can modify, and suggest further improvements. http://sourceforge.net/projects/risetemplate/

Comment: Sharelatex seems to provide a variety of different thesis formats from different universities.
Many formats are available [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/).

Answer (score 15):

Use the one that is provided by your institution.  The formatting guidelines are not "guidelines", but are instead "requirements" that are checked by someone who deeply cares about them.  So you should use a template that has successfully been used in the past at your institution.  If you do otherwise, you are setting yourself up for a **lot** of formatting work.  All of that said, University of Oregon's style file, which I used for my degree there, may be found here: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/uothesis

Comment: I agree with the recommendation that using an existing package/style file is the best way forward because this will save lots of time fiddling with style. However, I don't agree with the sentiment expressed that one should follow the ``house'' style because somebody in the home institution deeply cares for it. Usually the house style is enforced by people who don't care about/haven't got a clue about typography. I'd aslo be surprised if they care to check. I suggest you contact your thesis adviser if you want to use a non-standard style and use it if they're happy.

Comment: At least in some institutions margins, double-spacing, font, headers, ... are indeed requirements, and are checked by people who don't know anything about typography, but who will require compliance and send it back...

Comment: Incidentally, who is it inside a university that really cares about the thesis format? Obsessive-compulsive librarians?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni +1 for that.

Comment: I don't know who cares or why, I just know I had to re-TeX and re-print (on the special paper) many pages of my dissertation due to margin and layout issues before I could actually have my dissertation accepted by the graduate school. I have heard rumor that my experience is not unique.  I have also heard rumor that the absurd nitpicking is due to microfiche(!?) requirements, but do not know if that rumor is true.

Comment: I wish my university had guidelines, would save me a lot of time on deciding how to make things look.

Comment: @Peter: What makes you think the university has detailed guidelines, let alone requirements? My university has only one requirement, and that is Margin size (which is for purposes of ensuring the binding works). There is in many universities plenty of freedom. (Higher-ups at my uni says this is completely intentional.)

Comment: @Oxinabox Most universities I have encountered have them. I also recall commiserating with graduate students in other places about the (different!) ridiculous formatting requirements that we all had to suffer under. I'm glad to hear that this is not universal. Ask your higher-ups about their experiences at other places. I suspect getting burned by this elsewhere caused them to ensure that it didn't happen where you are.

Answer (score 5):

Look at these options, I personally prefer the third option as Latex is always the best.

1. http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/teaching/phd/
2. http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/c.clack/phd.html
3. http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/thesis/thesis_a4.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The following are all LaTeX related.

I really like Uggedal's thesis design. You may download the sources from https://github.com/jrk/uggedal-thesis.

Other starting points are Andre Miede's `classicthesis` and Lorenzo Pantieri's `classicthesis` packages.

```
@Manual{classicthesis,
    author    = {Miede, Andr{\'e}},
    title     = {The Classic Thesis Style},
    keywords  = {latex},
    date      = {2010-01-24},
}

@Manual{arsclassica,
    author    = {Pantieri, Lorenzo},
    title     = {Customizing \texttt{classicthesis}
                  with the \texttt{arsclassica} Package},
    keywords  = {latex},
    date     = {2010},
}
```

Comment: I love classic thesis. I am forking a version of that code for my own dissertation.